# How to find strings and add these string to an array

Tags: php

Anyone please help me..

```
$description = "This is product description. Quality is good. Title:title Price:1000 Size:XL, Medium, Small  Color:red, green, blue. Any one can buy freely. ";
```

I wanna find "Title:", "Price:", "Size:" and "Color:" from that string and I want to add those values in an array.

My desired output is:

```
$new_desc = array(
              'title'=>'title',
              'price'=>1000,
              'size'=>array(
                     [0]=>'XL',
                     [1]=>'Medium',
                     [2]=>'Small',
               ),
              'color'=>array(
                     [0]=>'red',
                     [1]=>'green',
                     [2]=>'blue',
               ),
);
```

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @Thyu I think my Answer solves your problem. Please mark it as accept so this question does not get any more unneeded attention.

Comment: @Thyu Did our Answers not solve your Problem? Why did you not accept an Answer?

Comment: @Thyu So what does "Thanks a lot!!!" mean to you if you don't even accept an answer nor feel the need to give feedback why you didn't?

Answer (score 0):

Using preg_match_all, you can [find you your identifiers](https://eval.in/144252) (Price, Size ...) and their Values. You then just have to alter that to fit your array form.

Read up on [preg_match_all](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) and Regular Expressions.

```
<?php

$string = "This is product description. Quality is good. Title:title Price:1000 Size:XL, Medium, Small  Color:red, green, blue. Any one can buy freely. ";
preg_match_all('/([^ ]{1,}):(([0-9a-z]{1,}|([0-9a-z,]{1,})( ))+)/i', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

So this gives you:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(11) "Title:title"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "Price:1000"
    [2]=>
    string(22) "Size:XL, Medium, Small"
    [3]=>
    string(22) "Color:red, green, blue"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "Title"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "Price"
    [2]=>
    string(4) "Size"
    [3]=>
    string(5) "Color"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "title"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "1000"
    [2]=>
    string(17) "XL, Medium, Small"
    [3]=>
    string(16) "red, green, blue"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "title"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "1000"
    [2]=>
    string(5) "Small"
    [3]=>
    string(4) "blue"
  }
  [4]=> [...]
}
```

if you iterate over the first set of matches from this array, you can create your desired output easily using [stripos](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) to find occurances of `,` and [explode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to generate arrays from your `,` seperated values.

```
$new_desc = array();
foreach ($matches[1] as $index => $identifier) {
  $value = $matches[2][$index];
  if(stripos($value, ',') !== FALSE) {
    $value = explode(',',$value);
  }
  $new_desc[$identifier] = $value;
}
var_dump($new_desc);
```

The full working DEMO can be found [here](https://eval.in/144252).

Comment: The OP requires the values after `:` as well, which this `preg_match_all` doesn't accomplish.

Comment: The result includes whitespace as well. Anyway, I've posted [my solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23382714/1438393) below :)

Comment: @AmalMurali As you can see in the included eval.in link, it does not include *unwanted* whitespaces. But *the more the merrier* right? ;-)

Comment: Check the values `[ Medium]`, `[ Small]`, `[ green]`, `[ blue]` — they all contain an extra whitespace. That's totally nitpicking though :)

Comment: @AmalMurali It is nitpicking :D

Answer (score 0):

Use [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/preg_match_all) to extract the key value pairs first:

```
preg_match_all('/[A-Z][a-z]+:[a-z\d, ]+/', $description, $matches);
```

Then loop through the `$matches` array and use [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) to create your result array:

```
foreach ($matches[0] as $value) {
    list($key, $qty) = explode(':', $value);

    if (strpos($qty, ',') !== FALSE) {
        $result[strtolower($key)] = array_map('trim', explode(',', $qty));
    } else {
        $result[strtolower($key)] = trim($qty);
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  ["title"]=>
  string(5) "title"
  ["price"]=>
  string(4) "1000"
  ["color"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "red"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "green"
    [2]=>
    string(4) "blue"
  }
}
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/144262)